# maven sure-fire plugin report empty

Tags: maven, junit, jenkins, soapui, maven-surefire-plugin

My requirement is to run multiple SOAPUI test cases via maven , automate it's build using jenkins and generate a report of the test results. 
I have successfully done except the last part.

Now i want to generate a html report of results of all the test cases.
I used maven-surefire-report-plugin to do so.

I have followed this article 
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/usage.html
The test case is successful and report is generated successfully but there are no records in the report.

[image]

Am i missing something here? Is there any configuration parameter to set the source path for generating reports or something?

surefire report is generated in **${project.build.directory}/site** folder.
Output files of the SOAPUI test case is generated at **${project.build.directory}/reports** folder.

This is the pom.xml i have written

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>soapTest</groupId>
<artifactId>soapTest</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Maven 2 SoapUI Sample</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <projectFile>soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</outputFolder>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                <printReport>true</printReport>
                <testSuite>Authenticate</testSuite>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: how did you enable surefire report in jenkins? i have add surefire plugin but the report still use basic junit report not surefire report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First line** of the Maven Surefire Report Plugin [Introduction](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/index.html) says:

> The Surefire Report Plugin parses the generated `TEST-*.xml` files under `${basedir}/target/surefire-reports` ...

So if you change your soapui-maven-plugin to:

```
<outputFolder>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
```

That should work.

There are also [additional instructions](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/report-custom-location.html) how to change the default location for the maven-surefire-report-plugin.

Comment: I did this change yesterday and could run the test and get the report successfully. Thank You! :)

Comment: I tried above but surefire dependency isn’t getting resolved. I am using SoapUI version 5.7.0 and everything works fine but not able to convert the Junit xml report to html report. Why the same plugin mentioned in question isn’t working for me?

Answer (score 0):

Sample pom.xml where reports are also being created with mvn site command.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Maven 2 SoapUI Sample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
        <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectFile>globalweather-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                            <outputFolder>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                            <printReport>true</printReport>
                            <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                            <globalProperties>
                                <value>ENV=DEV</value>
                            </globalProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```